# Flutter - Phone Call From Webpage Displayed in a WebViewScaffold

Tags: dart, flutter, mobile-development

Background: I am opening a website in my flutter app using a WebViewScaffold ([flutter webview plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)).  The website has a **call** option where you click a button and it launches the "tel://1231231234" url.

Problem: The WebView displays **Webpage not available**, etc. 
(Similar to the problem shown [here](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2015/09/17/fix-err_unknown_url_scheme-on-android-webview-for-telsmsgeoetc-links/)). 
I need this to work on both iOS and Android. How can I make this happen using the Flutter WebView Plugin on both device platforms?

I have seen several people who use intents (like the problem shown above) for Android only and are not using flutter.  Is this a problem for platform specific code?

Answer (score 0):

As show in the example of [Flutter Webview Plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin#-example-tab-) you can implement the following method for the change in the URL.

```
  _onUrlChanged = flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _history.add("onUrlChanged: $url");
        });
    if(url.contains("tel")){
    //implement for condition
       }
      }
    });
```

You can implement the required condition using [url launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher#-readme-tab-) package available with flutter and it works on both Android and iOS. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried this solution previously, the problem with this solution is that the **Webpage not available** message stays in the WebView and in order to make it work properly, I have to pop all navigation routes back to the home screen, then push the webpage route.  This is a problem because the user loses their place on the webpage (maybe could be fixed with saved state).  Not only that, this is not a very clean solution.

Comment: Then you have to implement the `_onStateChanged` i.e. when url starts to load. Try this `if (state.type == WebViewState.startLoad)
 {
              //implementation
            }`.
Access the url using `state.url`

Comment: While I can launch the url whenever the webpage starts to load, the **Webpage not available** page still loads in the WebView.  Somehow I need a way to prevent/cancel the url from loading in the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Made a little workout for this.

```
WebviewScaffold(
   url: link,
   invalidUrlRegex: Platform.isAndroid
   ? "^tel:|^https:\/\/api.whatsapp.com\/send|^mailto:"
   : "^tel:|^mailto:",
)
```

Added the whatsapp, tel and mailto in the invalid regex, so the WebviewScaffold will abort the operation, after caught them in onStateChanged

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged
    .listen((WebViewStateChanged state) async {
  if (mounted) {
    if (state.type == WebViewState.abortLoad) {
      _launchSocialNativeLink(state.url);
    }
  }
});

Future<void> _launchUrl(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

Future<void> _launchSocialNativeLink(String url) async {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    if (url.contains("tel:")) {
      _launchUrl(URL);
    }
  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    if (url.contains(":tel") ||
        url.contains("https://api.whatsapp.com/send")) {
      _launchUrl(URL);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in flutter webview, you have to check if the URL starts with

> 'tel':

you have to check it like this example:

```
if (request.url.startsWith('tel:')) {
    launch('tel:01761685693');
    return NavigationDecision.prevent;
}
```

or if you want to open in messenger than you have to pass like this:

```
if (request.url.startsWith('tel:')) {
    launch('https://m.me/111150717184573');
    return NavigationDecision.prevent;
}
```

Though you have to check if the URL can be launched or not, like this:

```
static launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```